# Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'

Tags: command-line

Every time when I enter my user in ubuntu I get this error:

> Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'

and I solved it by:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

but the problem is when I end the session and reenter, the same error appear ..

I'm beginner in using ubuntu OS, also I'm working in an account without sudo access ..

Edited: as @steeldriver requested in the comments:

```
> /usr/bin/diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
export PATH=/home/bghanem/python/python27/bin
export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: have you tried putting `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`

Comment: oh... definitley meant `~/.bash_profile`...

Comment: @justinbenge no, the problem was the `$PATH` that you forgot

Comment: @steeldriver , check it please ..

Comment: @Minion replace `diff` by `/usr/bin/diff` will typing the command; that the manual way to access at command; so the command of @steeldriver would be `/usr/bin/diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Steeldriver .. I got a result

Comment: so previously, you have done an export without adding the `$PATH`, now all previous export had been erased (and a file named `python27` is pretty interesting, must be `python2.7`)

Comment: @Melebius , the question that you mentioned is a personal device where he has root permissions, here I'm working in a cluster, with user account (no sudo access) ..

Comment: You should not need root permissions to edit your files. Anyway, I’ve posted [an answer tailored for you](https://askubuntu.com/a/1058695/250300) and retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 6):

According to the `diff` output, your problem is definitely inside your `~/.bashrc`. You should correct it by editing. (To edit files in your home directory (`~`), root permissions should not be necessary unless something else is messed up.)

In the first `export` command, you overwrite the current `PATH` contents by not including `$PATH`. To extend the existing list, the command should read:

```
export PATH="/home/bghanem/python/python27/bin:$PATH"
```

You can also merge both `export` commands into one.
Moreover, you should use `$HOME` instead of `~` when setting the `PATH` variable (thanks @DavidFoerster for the [explanation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058674/command-ls-is-available-in-bin-ls/1058695?noredirect=1#comment1732681_1058695)!), so the result is:

```
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$HOME/python/python27/bin:$PATH"
```

Use your favorite editor to edit the file. In your current situation, you might need to invoke it using the full path, e.g. `/bin/nano`. After that, don’t forget to reload `.bashrc` using `. ~/.bashrc` or by opening a new shell.

Comment: I did the same, but I got the same error again! : Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found

Comment: @Minion You need to reload the edited file, see [my update](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1058695/2).

Comment: yes I did that but it not work .. when I run the first command "the one with python", then then "source ~/.bashrc" .. If I checked this command: /usr/bin/diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc nothing changed ! the same output appeared

Comment: @Minion If nothing changed in the diff, you haven’t edited `~/.bashrc` properly. Or your command “the one with python” breaks things. In this case, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1058674/edit) to add details, e.g. the script contents.

Comment: which script contents ?

Comment: @Minion The command “the one with python”.

Comment: There's another problem: `PATH="~/..."` doesn't lead to tilde expansion. It should be `PATH="$HOME/..."` instead.

Comment: It's a Bash thing: [`PATH="~/bin" ./test-path-tilde-expansion my-program`](https://gist.github.com/davidfoerster/3df8b84a774d1a0ccb5a7b09e537ce9c) and `PATH="~/bin" dash -c 'exec my-program'` fail but `PATH="~/bin" bash -c 'exec my-program'` works. Thus programs relying on glibc to discover executables won't find them inside `~/bin`. If that's what you want, fine; otherwise use `$HOME` instead of `~`. (There's no mention of tilde expansion in the [manual of `exec*(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/execvp.3.html) either.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit 3 files :

- `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`

You must add your command line in both files, at the end (your command line is 
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin`)

- `/etc/environment`

You must add your command at the end of the file, but **without** `export` (in your case, just add `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin`)

Now, to apply your change, you have to reboot your computer, or you can also type these following commands which will apply these changes without reboot :

```
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.profile
```

NB : don't forget the `$PATH` inside your export, `PATH` isn't empty so you can have some issues if you forget to add it

Comment: I don't have permissions to do so , It's a user account in a cluster

Comment: don't you have access at `sudo` command?

Comment: no, "MY_USER_NAME is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported"

Comment: would be almost impossibleto solve, we need to have read and write access on system file (not for `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` but for `/etc/environment`)

Comment: it was working before a day with a problem, but when I was trying to install python virtualenv locally I did something wrong ..

Comment: @Minion you need `sudo` or root access to be able to install package, how do you proceed?

Comment: if so, how I edited it without any access ,, ?!

Answer (score 1):

open ./bashrc in any editor then write at the end of file

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

or you can add as many path appending to it  ":path" and then update it by

```
source ./bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it following the answer here: [Setting "export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin" permnently](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1800155)

I edited ~/.bashrc file:

```
pico ~/.bashrc
```

at the end of the file I found these lines:

```
PATH="/home/common/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH=/home/MY_USER/python/python27/bin 
export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

I added below them:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin"
```

and I saved it ..

Comment: I doubt this. The `export` statements after the `PATH=…` statements are pointless. And if the last line is really just `PATH="/usr/bin:/bin"` then your PATH will only contain these two directories (and not `/home/MY_USER/python/python27/bin`, for example). You definitely did not get those commands from the URL you refer to.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the scripts .. I copied them incorrectly .. the "export" is in the beginning .. for the second part "You definitely did not get those commands", I entered the script "/usr/bin/diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc" again, and all of them appeared except the first one "PATH="/home/common/bin:$PATH" .. you can try it ..

Comment: I cannot follow. But now I reckon that you just get `/usr/bin:/bin` when you type `echo $PATH`. Still not what you want.

Comment: Yes, this what I get .. but why not what I want ?!

Comment: I thought you wanted ...common..., ...anaconda..., ...python27..., AND `/usr/bin:/bin` in your PATH but now only have the latter.

Comment: I merged them in one command, the output: /home/common/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/bghanem/python/python27/bin:~/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin ..

Comment: `export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` is broken, because `~` is not expanded when quoted. Change the `~` to `$HOME` for it to have any effect.

Comment: That said, your main problem is the second one: `export PATH=/home/MY_USER/python/python27/bin`, because it doesn't honor the old `$PATH`, which *already includes* `/bin` and `/usr/bin` until you overwrite it with that command. If you change it to `PATH=$HOME/python/python27/bin:$PATH` (the `export`s aren't needed here -- for any of these lines), then you won't need the last `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`, and thus will avoid the harm that command causes (as it prevents your local Python and Anaconda PATH entries from having any effect).